# .htaccess prevent subdirectory browsing and update URL in browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, directoryindex

I'm trying to prevent browsing of files in a subdirectory by displaying a specific page, at the same time as preventing duplicate content on two URLs.

I have several files in a subdirectory, for example:

`www.example.com/subfolderA/pageone.html`

`www.example.com/subfolderA/pagetwo.html`

`www.example.com/subfolderA/pagethree.html`
etc

I do not want users to access the subdirectory itself (`www.example.com/subfolderA/`) and see a list of all the files.  Instead I would like them to be directed to a specific page (that isn't necessarily called "index.html"), let's say `pageone.html`.

I have put the following in a .htaccess file within that subdirectory:

`DirectoryIndex pageone.html`

Whilst this prevents browsing of files and shows my desired page, it results in duplicate pages appearing in search engines.

`www.example.com/subfolderA/` and `www.example.com/subfolderA/pageone.html`

How can I also ensure that the subdirectory itself doesn't get indexed by the search engines - i.e. always update the URL in the browser to `www.example.com/subfolderA/pageone.html`?

Also is this the best solution to meet my requirement?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove duplicate pages you can have this rule in `/subfolderA/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolderA/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/subfolderA)/?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %1/pageone.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response anubhava.  I've tried your code but I think this is the wrong way round.  I'm trying to ensure the URL in the browser is www.example.com/subfolderA/pageone.html NOT www.example.com/subfolderA/.  How would I achieve this?  Thanks.